# Orbit spaces of linear involutions on spheres

Tags: algebraic-topology, group-actions

Consider the following involutions ($\mathbb{Z}_2$-actions) on the unit $2$-sphere $S^2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$:

1. $(x, y, z) \mapsto (-x,-y,-z)$, the antipodal action; the orbit space is the projective plane $\mathbb{R}P^2$.
2. $(x, y, z) \mapsto (-x, -y, z)$, the rotation around the $z$ axis.
3. $(x,y, z) \mapsto (-x,y,z)$, the reflection along the $x$ axis, with the orbit space the $2$-disk $D^2$.

My first question is: what is the orbit space of the second involution? I've found a post on MathOverflow (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20836/involutions-of-s2) which states that it is again $S^2$, but why is that the case?

A follow-up question: what happens with the orbit spaces in higher dimensions? In dimension $n$ we have $n+1$ analogous involutions, varying by the number of "minuses". For the antipodal action, the orbit space is $\mathbb{R}P^n$; when there's only one "minus" (analogue of case 3), the orbit space is $D^n$. Can something be said in the remaining cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use polar coordinates on the $(x,y)$ plane and catesian on the $z$ axis.
Then the application
$$\varphi : S^2 \to S^2, \quad (\rho,\theta,z) \mapsto (\rho,2\theta,z)$$
is a [ramified covering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branched_covering) whose fibers are the orbits of your second involution.

More generally, in higher dimensions as you say you can classify the involution by the spectrum of the corresponding elements in $O^n$. Let's consider for $0 \leq i \leq n$ an involution $z_{i,n+1-i}$  of signature $(i,n+1-i)$ :

$$z_{i,n+1-i} : (x_1, \cdots, x_n, x_{n+1}) \mapsto (x_1, \cdots, x_i, -x_{i+1}, \cdots, -x_{n+1})$$

Then, you have a branched covering

$$\varphi_{i,n+1-i} : S^n \to E$$

where $E$ is the topological quotient space $D^i \times \mathbb{P}^{n-i} / R$, with $R$ being the equivalence relation defined as follows :
$$ \forall x\in S^{i-1} \subset D^ i, \forall y_1, y_2 \in \mathbb{P}^{n-i}, \quad (x,y_1) \sim (x,y_2).$$
You can think of $E$ as $D^i \times \mathbb{P}^{n-i}$ that collapses on the border $S^{i-1}$ of $D^i$.

$\varphi_{i,n+1-i}$ is then defined by :
$$\varphi_{i,n+1-i} : (x_1, \cdots, x_{n+1}) \mapsto \left(x_1, \cdots, x_i, \pi_{n-i}(x_{i+1}, \cdots, x_{n+})\right),$$
where $\pi_{n-i}$ is the canonical projection
$$\pi_{n_i} : \mathbb{R}^{n+1-i}\setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{P}^{n-i}.$$

Note that the fact that $\pi_{n-i}$ is not defined on $0$ is not a problem as it corresponds  to $(x_1, \cdots, x_i)$ being in $S^{i-1}$ so we can just let it undefined and map $(x_1, \cdots, x_i, 0, \cdots, 0)$ to the corresponding point in $E$.

On the other hand, the fibers of $\varphi_{i,n+1-i}$ are exactly the orbits of $z_{i,n+1-i}$, so $E$ is the orbit space.

Now, I understand that this answer may be incomplete because one would like to have a better description or understanding of $E$. While I am unable to give a better general answer, we can already discuss some special cases :

- If $i=0$, then $E$ is the projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$.
- If $i=n$, then $E$ is the closed ball $D^n$.
- If $i=1$, then $E$ is the [suspension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspension_(topology)) of $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}.$ That gave us a simple description for $n=2$ because of the exceptional case $\mathbb{P}^1 \sim S^1$, but that is not the case in general.

Comment: That's a nice answer, thank you!